# RHEL 8 AppStream does not contain PHP 7.1?

Tags: rhel, package-management, php7

I have a fresh RHEL 8 system. I thought I could install [PHP 7.1 via the Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php71/). But this package is not available.

Repository list:

```
$ sudo dnf repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Tools Repo                                                        1.9 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)          2.6 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)             2.2 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:01
repo id                           repo name                                                status
eww_ITandTEL_MaaS_Tools_Repo      Tools Repo                                                   1
nginx-stable                      nginx stable repo                                           22
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs) 5,764
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)    2,097
```

AppStream content:

```
$ sudo yum module list
[sudo] password for rsx:
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Tools Repo                                                                                                                                                              2.0 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                                2.6 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                                                                   2.3 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:01
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
Name                                Stream                    Profiles                                                Summary
...
perl-YAML                           1.24 [d]                  common [d]                                              Perl parser for YAML
php                                 7.2 [d]                   common [d], devel, minimal                              PHP scripting language
pki-core                            10.6                                                                              PKI Core
....
```

There is only version 7.2 available. What could be the reason that 7.1 is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 7.1 isn’t available for RHEL 8, even from [Rémi’s repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/). It was available during the RHEL 8 beta, but was removed before release, presumably because PHP 7.1 will reach its end of life in December. [The RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.0_release_notes/rhel-8_0_0_release#web-servers-databases-dynamic-languages) release notes only mention PHP 7.2.

It’s still available in Software Collections for RHEL 7, so if you need PHP 7.1 you’re probably better off staying on RHEL 7.

Comment: Oh... really? That's sad. But okay. Has this been announced anywhere? Do you have a link?

Comment: I’m only aware of the release notes; I don’t know of any public announcement that PHP 7.1 is not available, except the fact that it’s not mentioned in the release notes (and 7.2 is). See the link in my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One further question: Will there be further packages added for RHEL 8 (PHP 7.1 or PHP 7.3, ...) in AppStream/SoftwareCollections or will the list that I see with `sudo dnf module list` all that is available there, without upgrading to RHEL 9 at some time?

Comment: I don’t think PHP 7.1 is a candidate, for the reason given in the answer. PHP 7.3 could be; the best way to get what you’re after, as a RHEL customer, is to ask for it (really).